# WHERE NOT clause with additional type() operators

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempting to write a query using WHERE NOT with additional type() operators.

Here's a positive match that works properly and returns users who have visited a club during October, 2017.

```
MATCH (user:User)-[visited]->(club:Club) 
WHERE type(visited) >= "20171001" and type(visited) <= "20171031"
RETURN user;
```

Here's a WHERE NOT that works properly and returns users who have NOT visited a club.

```
MATCH (user:User) 
WHERE NOT ( (user:User)-[]->(:Club) ) RETURN user;
```

But I'm having trouble formatting a query properly that returns users who have NOT visited a club in October, 2017.

```
MATCH (user:User) 
WHERE NOT ( (user:User)-[visited]->(:Club) 
AND type(visited) >= "20171001" and type(visited) <= "20171031")
RETURN user;
```

This returns a "visited not defined" error. Which would seem to indicate that it needs to be defined in the initial match, but adding it to the initial match like this returns no records, so I'm stuck.

```
MATCH (user:User)-[visited]->(:Club) 
WHERE NOT ( (user:User)-[visited]->(:Club) 
AND type(visited) >= "20171001" and type(visited) <= "20171031")
RETURN user;
```

This evaluates, but returns no results. The issue is that it's looking for the visited relationship, so if a user has never visited a club, they won't match, and therefore, won't be returned as users who didn't visit in October.

Comment: "The issue is that it's looking for the visited relationship, so if a user has never visited a club, they won't match, and therefore, won't be returned as users who didn't visit in October." -- even for users who have visited a club, this query will not work: the `WHERE NOT` part of the query filter out all results that were selected by the `MATCH` clause.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative using OPTIONAL MATCH for the relationship to exclude, and then keeping only rows where such a relationship doesn't exist.

```
MATCH (user:User)
OPTIONAL MATCH (user)-[visited]->(:Club)
WHERE type(visited) STARTS WITH "201710"
WITH user
WHERE visited IS NULL
RETURN user
```

Answer (score 0):

As you observed, it's [not possible to introduce new variables in the `WHERE` clause](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/clauses/where/#query-where-patterns):

> Note that you cannot introduce new variables here.

I think the best approach is to list users who *did* visit a club in October, [`collect`](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.2/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) them to a list, then get all users and only return those who are not in the list.

```
MATCH (user:User)-[visited]->(:Club)
WHERE type(visited) >= "20171001" AND type(visited) <= "20171031"
WITH collect(user) AS visitorsInOctober
MATCH (user:User)
WHERE NOT user IN visitorsInOctober
RETURN user
```

Having said that, I believe your data model should be refined. Relationships can also have properties, so you could use define a relationship with the type `VISITED` and with a property `date`. This would result in a query similar to this:

```
MATCH (user:User)-[visited:VISITED]->(:Club)
WHERE visited.date >= "20171001" AND visited.date <= "20171031"
// ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'm not excited about having to build the list first and then evaluating that, but you may be correct. The reason that the relationship is formatted that way is to avoid issues with a super-node. This was advice directly from the Neo4J company.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is the simplest way to do it. Neo4j will feature [nested queries as the Cypher language develops](https://s3.amazonaws.com/artifacts.opencypher.org/website/ocig6/Nested%2C+updating%2C+and+chained+subqueries.pdf), but these are not yet available. Interesting remark on avoiding the supernode problem. How much data do you have?